# visual studio comunity 2019 install failed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

My system is win10（update today)
I have installed VS on my computer in the past, but I plan to reinstall it this year but it cannot be installed. I downloaded the installer and it crashed after opening it.

templog in dd_vs_BuildTools_decompression_log:

```
[5/4/2021, 2:38:29] === Logging started: 2021/05/04 02:38:29 ===
[5/4/2021, 2:38:29] Executable: L:\Downloads\vs_BuildTools (1).exe v16.9.31205.134
[5/4/2021, 2:38:29] --- logging level: standard ---
[5/4/2021, 2:38:29] Directory 'C:\Users\91931\AppData\Local\TEMP_~1\c0ce4931cb3919c158\' has been selected for file extraction
[5/4/2021, 2:38:29] Extracting files to: C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\TEMP_~1\c0ce4931cb3919c158\
[5/4/2021, 2:38:29] Extraction took 219 milliseconds
[5/4/2021, 2:38:29] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline '  --env "_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:L:\Downloads\vs_BuildTools (1).exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:L:\Downloads"'
[5/4/2021, 2:38:36] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
[5/4/2021, 2:38:36] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0x138a
[5/4/2021, 2:38:36] === Logging stopped: 2021/05/04 02:38:36 ===
```

and templog in dd_bootstrapper_20210504023830.log:

```
Beginning of the log. Start Time: 04/05/2021 2:38:30
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Commandline arguments = --env,_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:L:\Downloads\vs_BuildTools (1).exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:L:\Downloads
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Caught Exception: Type = DllNotFoundException, Message = Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.C2RSignatureReader.Native.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E), StackTrace =    at C2RSignatureReader.Interop.C2RSignatureReaderNative.ParseArguments(String path, String[]& argumentsArray)
   at C2RSignatureReader.Interop.C2RSignatureReaderInterop.ParseArguments(String path, String[]& arguments)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Parse(String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IC2RSignatureReaderInterop c2rSignatureReader, String entryAssemblyProcessName, String entryAssemblyProcessFullName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Run(String[] args)
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: General Failure. Message:Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.C2RSignatureReader.Native.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) Callstack:    at C2RSignatureReader.Interop.C2RSignatureReaderNative.ParseArguments(String path, String[]& argumentsArray)
   at C2RSignatureReader.Interop.C2RSignatureReaderInterop.ParseArguments(String path, String[]& arguments)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Parse(String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IC2RSignatureReaderInterop c2rSignatureReader, String entryAssemblyProcessName, String entryAssemblyProcessFullName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Run(String[] args) Inner Message: Internal Exception: 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: Sending Watson Bucket with:
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: P1  = vs_setup_bootstrapper
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: P2  = 2.9.3365.38425
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: P3  = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: P4  = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: P5  = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: P6  = n/a
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: P7  = 5002
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: P8  = -2146233052
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: P9  = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: P10 = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: Including dmp file
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:04/05/2021 2:38:31: Watson: Including Log : C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\Temp;\dd_bootstrapper_20210504023830.log
```

I tried almost every method, but I still can’t install it.